# Regex match multiline for group 3

Tags: regex

I have this pattern:

```
(BEGIN @\d+)\b(?s:.*?)(ACTION_READLN.*)\b(?s:.*?)(ACTION_IF.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/2

I need also to match every `'ACTION_IF *'` for group 3.

Comment: Something like [*this*](https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/3) should do the job I guess.

Comment: @HamZa but it also catches 'Text' after 'ACTION_IF ("ajantimer" = 4)' any way to avoid it?

Comment: heya, try [*this*](https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/5)

Comment: or [try that](https://regex101.com/r/uZ4yO8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your example and managed to capture all of them:

https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/6

With the following Regex:

`(BEGIN @\d+)\b(?s:.*?)(ACTION_READLN.*)\b(?s:.*?)(ACTION_IF.*\n)+`

Comment: Could you please take look at this: https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/7 and catch also the rest of `ACTION_IF` lines? @Yaron

Comment: What exactly are you after? I tried playing around with it and I came up with a solution for capturing all the `ACTION_IF` items but unselect the rest, here: https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/8

Comment: Thanks, i will use both of you pattern.